# Getting null value for @Value with @AllArgsConstructor

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting null as a value when I use @Value with @AllArgsConstructor combination.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ReconService{
    
    private ReconRepo reconRepo;
    private InService inService;
    @Value("${threshold.count}")
    private Integer threshold;
    
    public void doSomething(List<Record> records) {
       if(threshold < records.size()) {
         throw new RuntimeException("threshold exceeded");
       }
    }
}
```

In the `doSomething()`, I am getting `threshold` variable value as null
Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Are ReconRepo and InService beans?

Comment: The `@Value` is on the field not the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You can use @RequiredArgsConstructor to inject your beans via constructor and your threshold value to be injected with field injection. For that you have to make your beans final

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ReconService{
    
    private final ReconRepo reconRepo;
    private final InService inService;
    @Value("${threshold.count}")
    private Integer threshold;
    
    public void doSomething(List<Record> records) {
       if(threshold < records.size()) {
         throw new RuntimeException("threshold exceeded");
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create a constructor, you're telling spring boot container that class dependencies will be injected using it. In that case, dependency specifications like `@Qualified` or `@Value` need to be declared on constructor parameter. Because your constructor is being generated by lombok, it doesn't includes annotations on parameters.

Using `@Value` directly on the field works for field injection, but in your case you are using constructor injection.

For your code to work you'll need to do the following:

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ReconService{

    private ReconRepo reconRepo;
    private InService inService;
    private Integer threshold;

    public ReconService(
        ReconRepo reconRepo,
        InService inService,
        @Value("${threshold.count}") Integer threshold
    ) {
        this.reconRepo = reconRepo;
        this.inService = inService;
        this.threshold = threshold; 
    }

    public void doSomething(List<Record> records) {
        if(threshold < records.size()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("threshold exceeded");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For more information see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation#using-value-with-constructor-injection

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it makes no sense in this case to construct a ReconService without the `@Value` parameter.  Meaning using `@RequiredArgsConstructor` would allow one to construct it manually in an illegal state.

Answer (score 1):

When I used both @NoArgsConstructor and @AllArgsConstructor it worked.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ReconService{
    
    private ReconRepo reconRepo;
    private InService inService;
    @Value("${threshold.count}")
    private Integer threshold;
    
    public void doSomething(List<Record> records) {
       if(threshold < records.size()) {
         throw new RuntimeException("threshold exceeded");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll find that reconRepo and inService will be null.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, it will initialize only the fields marked with `@NonNull` or `final` keyword.

Comment: None of the fields in the question are marked `@NonNull` or `final`.